# How can I set the log level in glib

Tags: c, logging, glib

Is there a way to change the log level in glib so e.g. in a release version of an application the debug messages of g_debug won't be logged to the stdout? Do I really need to implement my own log handler for this (g_log_set_handler)?

Comment: A log handler can be a really simple function. I don't see why this is a big deal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have asked this question quite a while ago. However things have changed in newer glib version which I just have discovered.

Since glib version 2.32 debug messages are disabled and not shown by default. If you want to turn them on the environment variable G_MESSAGES_DEBUG needs to be set to all.

```
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all /path/to/application
```

This option might be suitable for you and there is no need for a log handler.

See details http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-running.html